# How to correctly pass an image as an argument to a class in opencv python

Tags: python, image, class, opencv

I am a newbie to python and opencv and when I try to run this code I get an error in the colors method while converting `BGR` to `HSV` as

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:7646: 
error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) in function cv::ipp_cvtColor
```

Even if I comment that part out and only run the part where it is simply returning the image as it is, it gives an error while displaying the image in cv2.imshow() as

```
cv2.imshow('image',res)

cv2.error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:281: 
error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Please help me figure out if I'm missing out on something.

```
class basicop:
@staticmethod
def colors(color, frame):
    if(color=='red'):
        lower = np.array([0, 100, 100])
        upper= np.array([10, 255, 255])
    elif(color=='green'):
        lower = np.array([86, 36, 99])
        upper= np.array([86, 255, 255])
    #CONVERT BGR TO HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower, upper)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask= mask)
    return frame

frame= cv2.imread('gree.jpg')
res=basicop.colors('green', frame)
cv2.imshow('image', res)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'): 
    cv2.imwrite('sanj.jpg', res)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: always add full error message.

Comment: add `print(frame)` after `cv2.read(...)`. If it prints `None` then you have problem with file `gree.jpg`.  It can be broken or it isn't in the same folder  as your script. Or you use wrong  name - maybe it should be `green.jpg`

Comment: it was not in the same folder, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error means that imread() can't read that image . But I saw you returned the frame in the color() where you should return the res .

```
class basicop:
    @staticmethod
    def colors(color, frame):
        if(color=='red'):
            lower = np.array([0, 100, 100])
            upper= np.array([100, 255, 255])
        elif(color=='green'):
            lower = np.array([50,50,50])
            upper= np.array([70, 255, 255])

        #CONVERT BGR TO HSV
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower, upper)
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask= mask)
        return res

frame= cv2.imread('img.jpg')
res=basicop.colors('green', frame)
cv2.imshow('image', res)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'): 
    cv2.imwrite('snL.jpg', res)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @Sanj probably, maybe you would want to change `mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower, upper)` to `mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)`, otherwise, you can remove `hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`

Comment: My bad it should be hsv in the inRange() thanks for pointing out